# What is a difference between "pylab" and "matplotlib.pyplot"?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to use MatPlotLib and I have realized that can import it in two different ways and in both cases it works (in the same way): `import pylab as p` or `import matplotlib.pyplot as p`.

So, my question is what is the difference between these two ways?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is the recommended way to plot: matplotlib or pylab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab)

Answer (score 4):

From the [official](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pylab-and-pyplot-how-are-they-related) documentation:

> Pylab combines the pyplot functionality (for plotting) with the numpy
>   functionality (for mathematics and for working with arrays) in a
>   single namespace, making that namespace (or environment) even more
>   MATLAB-like. For example, one can call the sin and cos functions just
>   like you could in MATLAB, as well as having all the features of
>   pyplot.

Note that pylab only imports from the top numpy namespace. Therefore, this will worK

```
import numpy
numpy.array # works
numpy.distutils # finds a module
```

And this will not

```
import pylab
pylab.array # works, is actually numpy array
pylab.distutils # gives an error
```