# Which is the recommended way to plot: matplotlib or pylab?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can **plot** in **Python** using either:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(...)
```

Or:

```
import pylab
pylab.plot(...)
```

Both of these use `matplotlib`.

Which is recommend as the correct method to plot? Why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The official documentation clearly recommends to use [`matplotlib.pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/pyplot_summary.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot).

The [API documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/) still mentions the [`pylab`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#module-pylab) module but advises against using it.<sup>1</sup>

> Since heavily importing into the global namespace may result in unexpected behavior, the use of pylab is strongly discouraged. Use [`matplotlib.pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/pyplot_summary.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot) instead.

The [Quick start guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/quick_start.html) also disapproves using the [`pylab`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#module-pylab) module.

> You may find older examples that use the pylab interface, via from pylab import *. This approach is strongly deprecated.

---

<sup>1. As far as I can see this recommendation was added on [February 7th, 2020](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/18d552d8b6172d3869b4d4791db6495b715f46cc)</sup>

Answer (score 113):

Official docs: [Matplotlib, pyplot and pylab: how are they related?](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related)

Both of those imports boil down do doing exactly the same thing and will run the exact same code, it is just different ways of importing the modules.

Also note that `matplotlib` has two interface layers, a state-machine layer managed by `pyplot` and the OO interface `pyplot` is built on top of, see [How can I attach a pyplot function to a figure instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254379/how-can-i-attach-a-pyplot-function-to-a-figure-instance/14261698#1426169)

`pylab` is a clean way to bulk import a whole slew of helpful functions (the `pyplot` state machine function, most of `numpy`) into a single name space.  The main reason this exists (to my understanding) is to work with `ipython` to make a very nice interactive shell which more-or-less replicates MATLAB (to make the transition easier and because it is good for playing around). See [`pylab.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/pylab.py) and [`matplotlib/pylab.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pylab.py)

At some level, this is *purely* a matter of taste and depends a bit on what you are doing.

If you are *not* embedding in a gui (either using a non-interactive backend for bulk scripts or using one of the provided interactive backends) the typical thing to do is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot(....)
```

which doesn't pollute the name space. I prefer this so I can keep track of where stuff came from.

If you use

```
ipython --pylab
```

this is equivalent to running

```
from pylab import *
```

It is now recommended that for new versions of `ipython` you use

```
ipython --matplotlib
```

which will set up all the proper background details to make the interactive backends to work nicely, but will not bulk import anything.  You will need to explicitly import the modules want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

is a good start.

If you are embedding `matplotlib` in a gui you don't want to import pyplot as that will start extra gui main loops, and exactly what you should import depends on exactly what you are doing.

Comment: The difference between pylab and pyplot is that the former imports numpy into its namespace. This was to make it behave more similarly with matlab. Using pyplot instead of pylab is preferred now because it is cleaner.