# Matplotlib: using a figure object to initialize a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am building a class of plot tools for a specific experiment.
I currently have two plot methods, a static plot using imshow(), and a "movie" format also
using imshow() .

Both methods and any future methods, get parameters that are the same for any specific plotting method that I might write. I have all those parameters in a config object at the time the plot class is used.

I don't want to rewrite code in every plot method. I would like to initialize an object (AxesImage I think) that will have these args set: vmin, vmax, extent_dim, Xlocs, Xlabels, Ylocs, Ylabels.

Then I just pass that object to various methods that do some other specific thing.
I don't understand how to do this...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = data_dict[type] # could be real part of a complex number, phase, or the mag...
v_min, v_max = self.get_data_type_scale(data_dict, Type)
freq = data_dict['freq']

# essentially sets the aspect of the plot since the x and y resolutions could be different   
extent_dim = self._get_extent(2)
# gets the labels for physical dimensions of the experiment
Xlocs,Xlabels,Ylocs,Ylabels = self._get_ticks(5,5,extent_dim)

# in the guts of a plot method, the basic idea is the call below.  

plt.imshow(data[0,:,:],cmap='jet',vmin=v_min,...
vmax=v_max,origin='lower', extent = extent_dim)

plt.title('Type:  %s  Freq: %.3e Hz' %(Type,data_dict['freq'][0]) )
plt.xticks(Xlocs, Xlabels)
plt.yticks(Ylocs,Ylabels)
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? If you want to initialize a `figure` object, then just do it. `fig = figure()` is all you need to do.

Comment: Let's say I make a handle to my plot:  im = plt.imshow(), then I can use im.set_extent((0,32,0,32)). Is this the proper way to pass around a plot object to methods. HOw do i get the plot to show? im.show() doesn't appear to work. Basically, how to I write good OO code with plots, where several arguments can be set in the __init__() and a reference to the object just passed to various methods.

Comment: What do you mean a handle? That sounds like MATLAB lingo, which is confusing here since Python has one thing: objects. In `matplotlib` there are `Axes` objects, `Figure` objects and tons of others. `im = imshow(randn(10, 10))` returns an `AxesImage` object. So...which one **exactly** are you talking about.

Comment: handle is bad...old matlab habit. I suspect I mean the AxesImage object.

Comment: Would you mind changing the title of your question to something a bit more descriptive, like 'changing default values of arguments to pyplot functions'.  Play jeopardy on the answer ;)

Comment: @tcaswell, I'm struggling with the name of the question. I feel like, yes, I want to know how to modify a plot's properties but it's also about how to write OO code with matplotlib. I don't want to repeat code, e.g., every plot method has a call to change the axes to the same values. I am also trying to control and remove choice for something that should be decided when the experimental conditions are conceived.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to understand a bit of architecture of `matplotlib` first (see [here](http://www.aosabook.org/en/matplotlib.html) for a long article by the founder and current lead developer).  At the bottom of the `backend` layer which deals with rendering and talking to the hardware.   On top of that layer are `artists` which know how to draw them selves by tell the `backend` object what to do.  On top of that layer is the `pyplot` [state machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab/16849816#16849816) interface which mimics `MATLAB`.

Everything you see in a figure is represented internally as an `Artist` and artists can contain other artists.  For example, the `Axes` object keeps track of it's children `Artists` which are the axes spines, tickes, labels, your lines or images etc and `Axes` objects are children of `Figure` objects.  When you tell a figure to draw itself (via `fig.canvas.draw()`) all the children artists are drawn recursively.

One draw back of this design is that a given instantiation of an `Artist` can be in exactly one figure (and moving them between figures is hard) so you can't make a `AxesImage` object and then keep reusing it.

This design also separates what `Artists` know about.  `Axes` objects know about things like tick location and labels and the display range (which it does by knowing about `Axis` object, but that is getting even more into the weeds).  Things like `vmin` and `vmax` are encapsulated in `Normalize` ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize)) objects which the `AxesImage` keeps track of.  This means that you will need to separate how you deal with everything on your list.

I would suggest either using a factory-like pattern here, or a curry-like pattern

Factory-like:

```
def set_up_axes(some, arguements):
    '''
    Factory to make configured axes (
    '''
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1) # or what ever layout you want
    ax.set_*(...)
    return fig, ax


my_norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin, mmax) # or write a factory to do fancier stuff
fig, ax = set_up_axes(...)
ax.imshow(..., norm=my_norm)
fig2, ax2 = set_up_axes(...)
ax2.imshow(..., norm=mynorm)
```

You can wrap up a whole set of kwargs to easily re-use them as such:

```
my_imshow_args = {'extent':[...],
                  'interpolation':'nearest',
                  'norm': my_norm,
                   ...}

ax2.imshow(..., **my_imshow_args)
```

Curry-like:

```
def my_imshow(im, ax=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    # do all of your axes set up
    ax.set_xlim(..)

    # set default vmin and vmax
    # you can drop some of these conditionals if you don't want to be
    # able to explicitly override the defaults
    if 'norm' not in kwargs:
        vmin = kwargs.pop('vmin', None)
        vmax = kwargs.pop('vmax', None)
        if vmin is None:
            vmin = default_vmin # or what ever
        if vmax is None:
            vmax = default_vmax
        my_norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin, mmax)
        kwargs['norm'] = norm

    # add a similar block for `extent` 
    # or any other kwargs you want to change the default of

    ax.figure.canvas.draw() # if you want to force a re-draw
    return ax.imshow(im, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to be super clever, you can monkey-patch `plt.imshow` with your version

```
plt.imshow = my_imshow
```

There is also the [rcParams](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) interface which will allow you to change the default values of many bits and pieces of `matplotlib` in a global way.

And [yet another](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1520/partial-function-application-in-python) way to accomplish this (through `partial`)

Comment: That's very helpful... :) I'll be referring to this for a while. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

To show a plot you'll want to use `fig.canvas.draw()` where `fig` is an instance of the `Figure` class. `fig.canvas.draw()` is the API version of the interactive shell (read: `pylab`) function `draw()`

If you need to get the `Axes` or `Figure` from an `AxesImage` object you can call either `im.get_axes()` or `im.get_figure()`, respectively.

As far as writing "good" object-oriented code [the user interface examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/index.html) might be good place to start.

Comment: to be picky, `pylab` is just a bucket to bulk import a bunch of useful stuff, `pyplot` is the state machine interface.

Comment: I also don't really understand how this addresses the question.

Comment: He asked how he can get the figure to show. Is `fig.canvas.draw()` not the accepted way to do that?

Comment: It addresses something asked in the comments, not in the OP.

Comment: The comments were a clarification of the original question.

Comment: The question boils down to 'how do I change the default arguments of imshow`, which is what a future user reading this will get.  Your answer isn't wrong, but is non-responsive to the main question here, and instead addresses how to get `Artists` objects to re-render.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for clarifying!