# how to insert a figure into a new subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a number of functions that return figures, like

```
def create_predef_plot():
    f, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(randn(10))
    return f, ax
```

how can i insert the plot returned by create_predef_plot into f2

```
plot1 = create_predef_plot()
f2, (ax21, ax22) = subplots(1,2)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284296/matplotlib-using-a-figure-object-to-initialize-a-plot/18302072#18302072 may be of interest

Answer (score 1):

1) this has nothing to do with IPython, it is pure matplotlib

2) the common pattern is to use an `ax` keyword argument.

```
def create_predef_plot( ax=None ):
    if not ax
        f, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(randn(10))
    return ax


f2, (ax21, ax22) = subplots(1,2)
create_predef_plot(ax=ax22)
```