# How to plot a heatmap from a matrix using matplotlib which would return a figure

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Below code plots a heatmap from a matrix, but it returns an image. I want a figure to be returned. Please let me know how would i achieve it.

```
from numpy.matlib import rand
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = []

i = input('Enter number of rows: ')
j = input('Enter number of columns: ')
for x in range(i):
    row = []
    for y in range(j):
        k = input('enter the value: ')
        row.append(k)
    A.append(row)
print A

figure(2)
plt.imshow(A, aspect=(0.1), interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', extent=(0, 10, 0, 100))
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('abc', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('xyz', fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The accepted answer for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284296/matplotlib-using-a-figure-object-to-initialize-a-plot) question is probably what you need.

Comment: I am unable to understand

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get a figure object, you should initialize it first with `fig = figure()`, but then you should also create your other objects as childs of `fig`, otherwise the returned figure will have nothing to do with your axes. That is why you should understand what is happening in the background.