# Add horizontal lines to plot based on sort_values criteria

Tags: python, loops, pandas, matplotlib, lines

**Question:**

How do I add horizontal lines to a `plot` based on the `sort_values` criteria specified below captured in the `top_5` variable.:

**Data:**

Here is a slice of the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/enfgmmyi2ydn62e/for_stack_nums?dl=0) in a CSV:

This is the **current** plot.

```
axnum = today_numBars_slice[['High','Low']].plot()
axnum.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
```

[image]

This is the data I want to add to this plot (the `High` and `Low` values from each row):

```
top_5 = today_numBars_slice[['High','Low','# of Trades']].sort_values(by='# of Trades',ascending=False).head()

top_5

High    Low # of Trades
Timestamp           
2017-01-02 12:55:09.100 164.88  164.84  470
2017-01-02 12:10:12.000 164.90  164.86  465
2017-01-02 12:38:59.000 164.90  164.86  431
2017-01-02 11:54:49.100 164.87  164.83  427
2017-01-02 10:52:26.000 164.60  164.56  332
```

**Desired output:**

This is an example of the desired output showing two of the lines from top_5:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use faster [`DataFrame.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) for top `5` rows and then [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) with [axhline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21129112/2901002):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df = pd.read_csv('for_stack_nums')
#print (df.head())

top_5 = df[['High','Low','# of Trades']].nlargest(5, '# of Trades')
print (top_5)
      High     Low  # of Trades
94  164.88  164.84          470
90  164.90  164.86          465
93  164.90  164.86          431
89  164.87  164.83          427
65  164.60  164.56          332

axnum = df[['High','Low']].plot()
axnum.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f')) 

for idx, l in top_5.iterrows():
    plt.axhline(y=l['High'], color='r')
    plt.axhline(y=l['Low'], color='b')
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Also subset is not necessary:

```
df = pd.read_csv('for_stack_nums.csv')
#print (df.head())

axnum = df[['High','Low']].plot()
axnum.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f')) 

for idx, l in df.nlargest(5, '# of Trades').iterrows():
    plt.axhline(y=l['High'], color='r')
    plt.axhline(y=l['Low'], color='b')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Would [`pyplot.axhline`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline) be what you're looking for?

```
axnum = today_numBars_slice[['High','Low']].plot()
axnum.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))

top_5 = today_numBars_slice[['High','Low','# of Trades']].sort_values(by='# of Trades',ascending=False).head()

for l in top_5.iterrows():
    plt.axhline(l['high'], color='r')
    plt.axhline(l['low'], color='b')

plt.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for trying.  I get the following Type error for line  : `----> 7     plt.axhline(l['high'], color='r')` .  Saying `TypeError: string indices must be integers`