# How to plot axline within each subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

**I'm trying to add an [`axline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axline.html) with `slope=1` to each of a series of subplots.**

- I'm following [the `axline` example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/specialty_plots/anscombe.html#sphx-glr-gallery-specialty-plots-anscombe-py) but it does not seem to work with my modifications.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129007/plotting-a-horizontal-line-on-multiple-subplots-in-python-using-pyplot) appears to be the closest question on SO, but doesn't answer my question

### Code attempts and errors

##### 01. As in `axline` example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(12, 10))
plt.xlim([-5, 10])
plt.ylim([-5, 10])
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.axline((0,0), slope=1, color='r', linewidth=2, linestyle='--')
```

> 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'axline'

##### 02. Within each subplot:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(12, 10))
row, col = 0, 0
for q in questions: # questions defined by my data
    question_scatter(df, q, row, col) # UDF to create a scatter plot in axes[row, col]
    axes[row, col].axline((0,0), slope=1, color='r', linewidth=2, linestyle='--')
    if row < 3:
        row += 1
    else:
        row = 0
        col += 1
```

> 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'axline'

##### 03. Apply globally:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(12, 10))
axes.axline((0,0), slope=1, color='r', linewidth=2, linestyle='--')
```

> numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'axline'

Comment: Your first code attempt works for me. what's your version of matplotlib? is it below 3.3.0?

Comment: Yes. `3.0.3`.  Grr... work computer. Will try to upgrade, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @suraj shourie points out, my first solution works if I upgrade `matplotlib` to `v3.3.0`.

For completeness:

```
$ pip install  -U matplotlib==3.3.0
```

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(12, 10))
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.axline((0,0), slope=1, color='r', linewidth=2, linestyle='--')
```