# How to know the version of installed pylab?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, version, anaconda

I seem to be having problems with installed packages. I need to know which version is installed pylab in my python 2.7.

The pylab module is in the following path (I have installed anaconda):
..../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py

Comment: might be useful to understand matplotlib vs pyplot vs pylab https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab/16849816#16849816

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As was mentioned by Ted Kim, "Matplotlib is the whole package; pylab is a module in matplotlib"

The version for matplotlib can be quired through:

```
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.__version__
```

Answer (score 2):

> Matplotlib is the whole package; pylab is a module in matplotlib.

Google says the site

http://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html