# pylab 3d axis log scale issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

So I am creaitng a 3d plot using matplotlib. The essential code snippet si shown below:

```
xScl, zScl = 'linear', 'linear'

data1, data2 = map(np.array, [data1, data2])

# Figure out the right scaling for different sets of data
if np.abs(data1).max() > 1000: 
    if data1.min() <= 0: 
        data1 = data1 - data1.min() + 1 
        # data1 = np.log10(data1)
        xScl  = 'log'
if np.abs(data2).max() > 1000: 
    if data2.min() <= 0: 
        data2 = data2 - data2.min() + 1 
        # data2 = np.log10(data2)
        zScl  = 'log'


for (n, f, d1, d2) in zip(ns, freqs1, data1, data2):

    ax.plot(    d1, [f/1e3]*len(d1), d2[abs(offset) <= 5], 
                's', mfc='None', mec=myCmap(n), label='%.3f Gbps'%(f/1e3))

    print d1.min(), d2.min()
```

Notice that I am scalling the data for proper scaling before plotting. There are two sets of data `data1` and `data2` which I plot on the `x` and `z` axes respectively. The `y` axis is a set of frequencies `freqs1` and is always the same so I dont need to worry about that. I also `print` the minimum values of each of the printed data sets `print d1.min(), d2.min()`. The result is shown below:

```
In [195]: run analysis.py
-0.510256538272 10041
-0.492209520677 10467
-0.514036247011 9954
-0.386102532864 26726
-0.38621630123 26719
-8.07925194343 1
-8.07925194343 1
-8.07925194343 1
-8.07925194343 1
-8.07925194343 1
-8.07925194343 1
-8.07925194343 1
-8.07925194343 1
-8.07925194343 1
-8.07925194343 1
-4.65764801656 2641
-2.87312441098 4616
-1.12656273628 9717
-0.796174863994 12101
-0.664695283706 14072
```

As can be seen, the second column (which should become log-scaled) is changed such that the minimum value becomes 1. This is what I want. Also, the `xScl == 'linear'` while `zScl == 'log'` at the end of the checks.

However, when I try to set the z-scale, like so:

```
ax.set_xscale(xScl)
ax.set_zscale(zScl) # <-- problem occurs here
```

I get an error:

```
In [196]: run analysis.py
-0.510256538272 10041
[... some deleted lines here ...]
-1.12656273628 9717
-0.796174863994 12101
-0.664695283706 14072
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

[... some deleted lines here ...] 

    151     ax.set_xscale(xScl)
--> 152     ax.set_zscale(zScl)
    153
    154     pl.show()

[... some deleted lines here ...] 

ValueError: Data has no positive values, and therefore can not be log-scaled.
```

Which is not the case, as we can see from the printed results. The minimum value is `1`, which should be ok.

On the other hand, if I manually take the logarithm within the code above:

```
if np.abs(data1).max() > 1000: 
    if data1.min() <= 0: 
        data1 = data1 - data1.min() + 1 
        data1 = np.log10(data1)
        # xScl  = 'log'
if np.abs(data2).max() > 1000: 
    if data2.min() <= 0: 
        data2 = data2 - data2.min() + 1 
        data2 = np.log10(data2)
        # zScl  = 'log'
```

This works fine. Which means that there is nothing wrong with my data. However, I dont want to plot it this way. I want to see the actual numbers, but the axis scaled to log. Looks like a problem with Matplotlib? Not sure.

I am using

Windows 7,

Pyhton(x,y),

Python version : Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

pylab.**version** --> '1.8.0'

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What version of mpl are you using?  I think `pylab.__version__` in picking up your numpy version.  I think we fixed this for 1.4.0.

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab/16849816#16849816

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  My mpl version is '1.3.1'. I'll try to upgrade to the latest version and post any update.