# MatPlotLib in Canopy requires PySide

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use the MatPlotLib library on Windows 7, and to that end I am using Enthought Canopy to make the installation process simpler. However, upon importing Pylab with `import pylab`, I get "ImportError: No module named 'PySide'". As I understand, PySide is provided with Canopy, thus I don't understand why can't it find it? On the package list of Canopy there is no PySide, and I can't import it. How do I tell the interpreter to use PySide provided with Canopy, and if I can't, how else do I use MatPlotLib?

Comment: As far as I understand, using the `pylab` import is no longer recommended. So just use `matplotlib`, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab). If you are using a tutorial or something that is telling you to use `pylab`, it is probably woefully out of date.

Comment: When asking about an error you would need to provide the full error traceback. To avoid the error you can try using a different backend, `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` since Tk should be included in python itself.

Comment: I also tried using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` just like in that question, but the error remains the same: ImportError: Matplotlib qt-based backends require an external PyQt4, PyQt5,
or PySide package to be installed, but it was not found.

Comment: @Spideyyyy that isn't the error you originally reported at all.

Comment: Adding `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` at the beginning seems to have fixed it. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, if you write it in an answer I can accept it.

Comment: This is not the answer, it's the test to see where the error comes from. The answer is to install PyQt4 or PyQt5.