# How to plot a branched sin(x) function

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, plot

I'm a noob practicing how to use pylab, matplot lib etc.

Somehow I'm not able to plot this simple branched sin(x) function in pylab/matplotlib.

```
from math import sin
import pylab as plb

def f(x):
    if sin(x) > 0:
        return sin(x)
    else:
        return 0

x = plb.linspace(-4,4,10000)

plb.plot(x,f(x))
plb.show()
```

The following error outputs when I run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/...plot.py", line 12, in <module>
    plb.plot(x,f(x))
  File "C:/Users/......plot.py", line 5, in f
    if sin(x) > 0:
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: At the risk of distracting from the question: matplotlib's official docs have discouraged the use of the `pylab` module since at least 2018: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inbuilt `sine` function inside math module accepts only a scalar value. You can use `numpy sine` instead to accomplish your plot as it accepts an array.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plb


def f(x):
    sine_ =  np.sin(x)
    sine_[sine_< 0] = 0
    return sine_
    
x = plb.linspace(-4,4,10000)

plb.plot(x,f(x))
plb.show()
```

The output is as shown below:

[[image]]

However, as pointed out by [Trenton McKinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758804/trenton-mckinney), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51011921/3896008) states the use of pylab is no longer recommended. So, the alternate solution using `matplotlib.pyplot` is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(x):
    sine_ =  np.sin(x)
    sine_[sine_< 0] = 0
    return sine_
    
x = np.linspace(-4,4,10000)

plt.plot(x,f(x))
plt.show()
```

The output is the same as the image above.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was very helpful :-)