# How can I colour my 3d graph, used fourth variable's value?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, graphics, 3d

I want to build the graph of complex function and use Matplotlib for that. But it can visualize only value of three variable and i want colour my graph as light as much value of fourth variable. Matplotlib allows to do that only with third variable's value.
My code (still without fourth variable):

```
import pylab as pl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

def makeData ():
    x = np.arange (-10, 10, 0.1)
    y = np.arange (-10, 10, 0.1)
    xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    zgrid = np.sin (xgrid) * np.sin (ygrid) / (xgrid * ygrid)
    return xgrid, ygrid, zgrid

x, y, z = makeData()

fig = pl.figure()
axes = Axes3D(fig, auto_add_to_figure=False)
fig.add_axes(axes)

axes.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, cmap = cm.jet)
pl.show()
```

Exactly this code uses value of z and colour graph:

```
axes.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, cmap = cm.jet)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please implement your code using standard import aliases `import numpy as np` `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Also, don't use pylab, as per [Which is the recommended way to plot: matplotlib or pylab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16849483/7758804), it is officially **disapproved**.

Comment: You're reusing a decade old piece of code,... Pylab, Axes3D are very out of fashion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reusing a decade old piece of code,... Pylab, Axes3D are very out of fashion!

I'll show you how you can implement your idea using modern Matplotlib.

`ax.plot_surface` supports the `facecolor=array` keyword argument, where `array` is an array of RGBA colors with the same shape as `X`, `Y` and `Z`, that you can generate from the array of 4th values using a colormap and a norm.

```
In [31]: import numpy as np
    ...: import matplotlib as mp
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...: 
    ...: fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="3d"),
    ...:                        constrained_layout=1)
    ...: x = y = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
    ...: X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    ...: Z = X+Y # elevations
    ...: V = X-Y # 4th value
    ...: 
    ...: norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=V.min().min(), vmax=V.max().max())
    ...: ax.plot_surface(X, Y, V, facecolors=plt.cm.plasma(norm(V)))
    ...: m = mp.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.plasma, norm=norm)
    ...: plt.colorbar(m)
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Tkank you, very much! Sorry, for this "old piece of code" i'm only styding and use this code to undestand how it work. One more thank to you, your code really help me!

Comment: @MrSparrow You're welcome, thank you for recognizing my answer. Re "old piece of code", it was not intended as a reproach but as a remark, to justify the different approach that I pursued in my answer (I know very well that teachers sometimes  throw very old pieces of software into their pupils…;-).