# How to change the plot style for python fitter package

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to learn how to change the look of `fitter`'s output plot. Here is the example

```py
import fitter as ft
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
from numpy.random import lognormal

data = lognormal(size=1000)

d = ['expon','weibull_min','pareto','gengamma','lognorm']
f = ft.Fitter( data, distributions=d, bins=50)
f.fit()
f.summary()
```

output:

[image]

I need to change the colors (both the histogram and the lines) and add some edge lines to the bins. I tried some matplotlib codes to change the grid style and remove some of the borders (below). But that's it.. I cant change the histogram and plot lines:

```py
f.summary(lw=1.3)

mp.gca().set_axisbelow(True)
mp.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
mp.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)

mp.gca().grid(color='#cccccccc', linestyle=':', 
              linewidth=0.7, which='both')

mp.show()
```

Comment: (Side note): Gah, `fitter` uses `pylab` under the hood... that's terrible.

Comment: The official `matplotlib` documentation states not to use `pylab`:  [Which is the recommended way to plot: matplotlib or pylab?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51011921/7758804). You should just directly use [`scipy.stats`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html), `pandas`, and `matplotlib`

Comment: i don't understand the negative vote... is something wrong with the question?

Comment: [`def summary`](https://github.com/cokelaer/fitter/blob/main/src/fitter/fitter.py#L441) does not **appear** to return the plot object, so you may be SOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an indirect solution. As mentioned in the comments above `fitter` uses `pylab` and it makes styling hard. But with help of `seaborn` and `cycler` it still can be done:

```
import seaborn as sns
from cycler import cycler

sns.set_theme()
sns.set_style(rc = {'axes.facecolor': 'w'})


mp.rc('lines', linewidth=1.5, linestyle='-')
mp.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler(color=['#20202077',
                                               '#029020dd',
                                               '#FF8C00dd',
                                               '#ff00ffcc',
                                               '#2020ffdd']
                                               # alpha=[1, 1, 1, 1, .7]
                                          )

f.summary(plot=True, lw=2)

mp.gca().set_axisbelow(True)
mp.gca().grid(color='#cccccccc', linestyle=':', 
              linewidth=1.5, which='both')

mp.show()
```

output:

[image]