# Trying to fit data to a curve and getting "OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated " scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I have some experimental data from a wind tunnel and I'm trying to fit a curve to this data and determine the x-intercept from it but cannot seem to get it to fit properly.

Plot of my experimental data:

[image: Plot of my experimental data]

Desired plot:

[image: Desired plot]

My Arrays for x and y are as follows below:

```
x = [0.05068111 0.04818916 0.04882654 0.05214874 0.05944521 0.07145887 0.0815519  0.09417571 0.11834393]

y = [0.0963202  0.22971568 0.36601308 0.50110841 0.63746987 0.77172614 0.85511004 0.90326404 0.94890827]

x = CD[3:12]
y = CL[3:12]

print(x)
print(y)

def fit_func(x, Cdmin, k1, Clmind):
    return ((x-Cdmin)/k1)**0.5 + Clmind

params = curve_fit(fit_func, x, y)

[Cdmin, k1, Clmind] = params[0]

print([Cdmin, k1, Clmind])
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What values for `Cdmin`, `k1`, `Clmind` did you expect to get? What does the plot look like if you use these values manually and don't try to do a fit?

Comment: Hi, I don't have values for Cdmin and Clmind so I am trying to fit the curve to determine these values. I have a good value for k from a previous curve fit but first was trying to curve fit to see what value I would get for it. For example, k should typically be 0.7 - 0.85. Thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you tried to fit a non-function, as one x-value here has two y-values. If you however invert the relation and calculate `Cd` as function of `Cl`, it works.

Also, the fit is not very good when including all the data points. I suspect some non-ideal conditions towards the end. You get a much better fit when leaving out the last two points.

```
from matplotlib import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = [0.05068111, 0.04818916, 0.04882654, 0.05214874, 0.05944521, 0.07145887, 0.0815519,  0.09417571, 0.11834393]
y = [0.0963202,  0.22971568, 0.36601308, 0.50110841, 0.63746987, 0.77172614, 0.85511004, 0.90326404, 0.94890827]

x2 = x[:-2]  # removing last two data points
y2 = y[:-2]

def cd_calc(cl, Cdmin, k1, Clmind):
    return k1 * (cl - Clmind) ** 2 + Cdmin


params, cov_param = curve_fit(cd_calc, y2, x2)
print(params)

x_hat = [cd_calc(y_i, *params) for y_i in y]
print(x_hat)

pylab.plot(x, y, "b.")
pylab.plot(x_hat, y, "k-")
pylab.xlabel("Cd")
pylab.xlabel("Cl")
pylab.grid()
pylab.show()
```

Resulting plot:

[image: resulting plot]

But I get `k1=0.1` not `0.7` to `0.85` as you wish. The curvature would then be much stronger as in your data points.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using pylab rather than pyplot?

Comment: @jared: Absolutely not ;-), just a habit I should probably review.

Comment: @jared: Thanks for mentioning it. I wasn't aware of the differences (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab)