# matplotlib.pyplot vs matplotlib.pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I usually use the following package to create my plots: `matplotlib.pylab`. However, there is also a package called `matplotlib.pyplot`.

I have not been able to spot any difference between the two when using them. So my question is the following:

What is the difference between the packages `matplotlib.pylab` and `matplotlib.pyplot`. In which cases would you advice one over the other?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560477/what-is-a-difference-between-pylab-and-matplotlib-pyplot?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is the recommended way to plot: matplotlib or pylab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab)

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469336/what-is-the-difference-between-pylab-and-pyplot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per [the FAQ](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pylab-and-pyplot-how-are-they-related):

> Pyplot provides the state-machine interface to the underlying plotting
>   library in matplotlib. This means that figures and axes are implicitly
>   and automatically created to achieve the desired plot....
>
> Pylab combines the pyplot functionality (for plotting) with the numpy
>   functionality (for mathematics and for working with arrays) in a
>   single namespace, making that namespace (or environment) even more
>   MATLAB-like. For example, one can call the sin and cos functions just
>   like you could in MATLAB, as well as having all the features of
>   pyplot.
>
> **The pyplot interface is generally preferred for non-interactive
>   plotting (i.e., scripting).** The pylab interface is convenient for
>   interactive calculations and plotting, as it minimizes typing. (my emphasis.)

Note that

```
from pylab import *
```

also performs

```
from numpy import *
```

This overwrites many builtin Python functions such as:

```
In [5]: import __builtin__
In [6]: import numpy as np

In [5]: {name for name in set(dir(np)).intersection(dir(__builtin__)) if not name.startswith('__') and getattr(__builtin__, name) != getattr(np, name)}
Out[5]: {'abs', 'all', 'any', 'max', 'min', 'round', 'sum'}
```

Therefore, I don't like `from pylab import *` (or really `from module import *` for any module) because it makes well-known beloved Python names behave in unexpected ways (if you do not always keep in mind that `from numpy import *` has polluted the global namespace.)

For example,

```
In [32]: np.all([np.arange(3), np.arange(3)])
Out[32]: False
```

while

```
In [33]: all([np.arange(3), np.arange(3)])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```